# How can I completely zero out all free blocks (deleted files)

Tags: backup, rm, dd, compression, gzip

I'm making a backup of Raspbian (I know, this isn't the Raspberry Pi SE, but it's a Linux question and it probably isn't just Raspbian that has this problem and BTW, the size of the drive is 128GB). The first backup is only 68GB after compression. Then, I deleted the first backup. The next backup is over 100GB in size! If I deleted the second backup and do another one, I run out of space when making a backup (since I use `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1M | gzip – | dd of=~/Desktop/backup-23-may-2020.gz` and since the unused space isn't all zeros, the compression is getting worse)

To my knowledge, deleting a file using `rm` just marks that file deleted, instead of zeroing out the file. I want to be able to completely zero out all the deleted files so when I back up the whole disk, the compression is better because all the unused space are zeros.

Will this command do that? (You will need to install `pv` (pipe viewer) if you want to try out this command by running `sudo apt install pv`)

```bsh
dd if=/dev/zero | pv -s 100g -S | dd of=~/zeros.txt
```

**EDIT 2:** Forgot the `=`. Thanks @Hermann.

I don't want to blindly execute this command because I did compile OpenCV on here and I refuse to do that again.

**EDIT:** According to `df -h` I have 102G of memory.

```bsh
pi@raspberrypi:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       115G  7.9G  102G   8% /
devtmpfs        1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.7G   26M  1.7G   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
...
```

Comment: It's possible but it'll likely waste a lot of write cycles on your SD card. Why not backup files instead of full raw image?

Comment: I compiled OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi. I refuse to go through that again.

Comment: What does OpenCV have that's not in the file tree?

Comment: I've also edited `rc.local` (much to everyone's dislike of it) and installing and configuring Raspbian would take too much time than just backing up the raw image. (BTW, I do use `gzip`)

Comment: And, you can burn the raw image directly to a disk and plug it back in to the Raspberry Pi and it "just works".

Comment: Would not `tar` and `zip`, not be a better way to do the backup?

Comment: If you want `pv` then you don't need `dd`: `</dev/zero pv >~/zeros`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this command do that?

It is missing the `=` after the `if`, but apart from that: Yes. I do not know whether it is the most efficient way to achieve it, but it will to the job.

Though I recommend a dd-only variant like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=~/zeros.txt bs=16M status=progress
```

No need for `pv`.

For complete root file-system backups, I recommend an offline-backup with `e2image`: Power down the pi, move the card into a PC, do *not* mount the root partition. Instead, shrink it with `resize2fs -M`, create a copy with `r2image -rap`, then expand it again with `resize2fs`.

Using `partclone` is probably even better, but I have no first-hand experience with it.

Comment: Oops, forgot the `=`. Thanks.

Comment: But I will say this, running it through `pv` is definitely slower than doing it directly. Already at 3.8GB.